# Intuition behind receive a straight in poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know the answer is on wiki and other sites, but I am looking for some intuition of how to get there. Given that I am being dealt 5 cards from a well shuffled deck, there are $52 \choose 5 $ ways to pick these. Now, for a straight to occur:

There are 10 ways to pick the first card ( This could be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ), So we have $10\choose 1$ possibilities. Now the remaining four cards are constrained to being the next ascending 4 numbers: So there are $4 \choose 1$ way to pick the second card, $4 \choose 1$ way for the second,...

So in total, there should be $10\choose1$ ${ 4 \choose 1}^4$, but the answer should be $10\choose1$ ${ 4 \choose 1}^5$? What's the intuition behind this? Or am I thinking about the whole problem incorrectly?

Also, if the first card is any of 5,6,7,8,9,10, shouldn't we multiply the frequency by 2 since we can either go backwards of forward to make a straight? ie. if first card is a 5, we need either 6,7,8,9 or 1,2,3,4

Comment: In your count, you seem to be including straight flush among the straights. Then the lowest card (if Ace can be either low or high) can be chosen in $40$ ways, and the rest in $4^4$ ways.  If we don't want to include the straight flushes, we subtract $40$.

Comment: so the extra 4 im confused about is just coming from the fact we have 4 suits?

Comment: Yes, each of the $5$ cards can be of any of the $4$ suits. It is potentially misleading to write "first card," since in $\binom{52}{5}$ we are neglecting the order of dealing.

Comment: $\binom{10}{1}$ only accounts for the "rank" (whether A, 2, 3, etc.) of the first card.  You still have to pick a suit for that first card.  This can be done in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

Comment: I believe that you can also think that your "first" card is just any card. For instance consider the positions: __ __ __ __ __. Let's say your first card is chosen for blank number 3. Even then the reasoning still applies since you still need to choose cards for blank numbers 1,2,4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10$ different lowest ranks, as you've pointed out.  Once you pick the lowest rank, you have four choices for the lowest card (one of each suit), four choices for the second lowest, etc.  That yields $10 \cdot 4^5 = 10240$.

From that must be subtracted the number of straight flushes (which are rated higher than straights, of course!), which can be reasoned out in a similar way.  There are again $10$ different lowest ranks, and then four choices for the lowest card (one of each suit), but after that only one choice for each of the four remaining cards.  That yields $10 \cdot 4 = 40$.

Since every straight flush was counted as a straight originally, the number of straights (that are not also straight flushes) is $10240-40 = 10200$.